# Website doesn't work with Safari but works with other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I created a website with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It's a simple website and it works on all browsers with the exception of Safari. The only part that doesn't seem to be working is when I have my media query in my CSS for larger screens (I built it for mobile first and it works great with mobile, even on Safari).

I looked at caniuse.com and it says I can use @media with Safari. I'm at a loss as to why it looks different. Not even sure what code to show you so I'm including my github repo with the files on it.

Any suggestions as to where I can look to see what I'm doing wrong are appreciated.

Thanks Overflowers!

https://github.com/KBiz65/finding-blueberries

P.S. I did make sure Javascript was enabled in my Safari preferences. The JS stuff seems to work fine, it's the layout not working.

[image]

The published website is at: https://www.findingblueberries.com

Comment: Can you include a minimal version of the part that isn't working here in a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using vscode,install [watch sass extension,(more info here)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass),create a style.scss file in your styles folder,copy all your initial css into style.scss file,Click to Watch Sass from Statusbar to turn on the live compilation,press ctrl+s to save style.scss file,a new file will be created called style.css,this will be compatible with all the browsers.link this file to your site.and let us know how this goes

Comment: I am using VS Code so this is great. I'm going to do it all now and I'll keep you posted!

Comment: I've installed the extension but it keeps saying "Extension host terminated unexpectedly." and gives me the options to open developer tools or restart extension shost. When I restart, it just does it again.

Comment: I found a "fix' that seemed to work for people but it doesn't seem to work for me. I still get the following error. "Extension host terminated unexpectedly."

The fix was to add "color-highlight.languages": [ "*", "!scss" ] to my .json settings but that doesn't seem to work either. I know my VS Code was set up by a senior developer who I know longer have any contact with. Any chance a setting could be changed on my system? Know anyone I could ask? LOL

Comment: Hi Joshua,

I was able to get it to work on another computer and the file compiled. I added that new .css file to my code and it's still not working. :-/ Any other ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: @K-Biz apologies i took so long to reply, I had similar problem with my vs too, all i did is reinstall it again.and everything worked for me,

Comment: okay that was great, did the new.css work on other 'persons' safari browser?,then I its just funny to ask but happens sometimes did you link the new css and unlink the order one?..lemme dive to your github and try to help out on my side, another ideas to troubleshoot,yeah i do have something running in my mind, when i face such problems I inspect each element using browsers debuggers,

Comment: So for some reason I couldn't get it to work on my VS Code on my mac. I think it's because I had a senior developer set up my system with a bunch of things installed that are probably causing problems. I was able to go on my windows laptop and install the extension so it was able to work. 

I did unlink the original css file and linked the new style file and it still didn't work. I'm not sure.

The github repo it is on is: https://github.com/KBiz65/finding-blueberries

I did put it back the way it was since it still wasn't working but I'll add a branch with the style.css file.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm definitely thrown for a loop here as to what's happening and I admittedly am not experienced enough to have seen this issue before.